# "File not found" when trying to download a file from URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have files stored on S3 and I want to be able to force download them.

For the purpose I came up with the following route :

```
Route::get('/download/{link}','HomeController@download');
```

And Controller function :

```
 public function download(Request $request, $link){

        $filename = 'S3 FILE';
        $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
        copy($link, $tempImage);

        return response()->download($tempImage, $filename);

    }
```

View:

```
    <a href="/download/{{url($uploads[0]->txtURL)}}" download="download">Download</a>
```

I don't know why when I click on the link the file doesn't download but instead i am getting a

> File not found
>
> Firefox can't find the file at
>   http://learn-laravel.dev/download/https://bbbucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/*******.txt.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot? What I want to do is to `force download` the file on the S3 link.

Comment: The URL being passed in is most likely being parsed into the laravel URL, so the route it's trying to find is `/download/{https:}/{}/{bbbucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com}/{*******.txt}`. Pass the URL in as a GET variable instead of a URL variable.

Comment: @aynber, can you demo this?

Comment: `/download?url=https://bbbucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/*******.txt` is how you'll want to access it, so it doesn't attempt to parse the URL into separate variables.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: Try to use urlencode in the path

Comment: can you provide any real s3 file link ? without placeholder? just to confirm that file exists and open to public?

Comment: are you sure that S3 https files are accesible form php? check your `copy()` function on server in cli mode. if copy itself does not work - check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612484/copy-file-from-https-url to enable ssl

Comment: Yes, they are. I just marked the answer that worked for me. You can have a look.

Comment: Cool. I am glad to hear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below my solution

Routing

```
Route::get('/download','HomeController@download');
```

Controller

```
public function download() {
    //get url from request
    $link = request()->input('url');

    $filename = 'S3 FILE';
    $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
    copy($link, $tempImage);

    return response()->download($tempImage, $filename);
}
```

Request

```
http://learn-laravel.dev/download/?url=https://bbbucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/*******.txt
```

Remember to use urlencode relative to the url parameter

```
http://learn-laravel.dev/download/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbbbucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com%2F%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A.txt
```

View

```
<a href="{{ route('download') }}?url={{ urlencode($uploads[0]->txtURL) }}" download="download">Download</a>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it didn't work. Maybe I got something wrong. I have updated my question and included the link from the view.

Comment: Please note that I am not using full URL as part of a route.

Answer (score 0):

> **I don't know why when I click on the link the file doesn't download but instead i am getting a...**

You will need to use the `url()` helper to encode your request.

```
<a href="{{ url('https://path/to/s3/file') }}">Download S3 file.</a>
```

**Note:** The url needs to be a fully qualified URL for it to be sent elsewhere.

---

> **From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url)**
>
> The `url` function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path.

So, if given `url('/posts')` generates `http://localhost:8000/posts`.

Given `url('http://yourdomain.com/about')` generates `http://yourdomain.com/about`.

---

Instead of:

```
<a href="/download/{{url($uploads[0]->txtURL)}}" download="download">Download</a>
```

Try:

```
<a href="{{ url($uploads[0]->txtURL) }}">Download</a>
```

**Note:** What goes into the `url(...)` needs to have format: [scheme://domain/path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it didn't work. Maybe I got something wrong. I have updated my question and included the link from the view. Can you perhaps provide a more detailed answer?

Comment: but if i use <a href="{{ url($uploads[0]->txtURL) }}">Download</a> then I am not using my controller function at all. And my goal is to "force" download this file.